# Detection and get position in TensorFlow

Tags: android, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

how can you take the position of an object detect from the camera with tensorflow in android?
i need it to print a new 3D object in that position.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below example available in Tensorflow site for getting detections from Camera

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android

This example shows on how to setup an object detector in Android and get positions of the object detected.